# How to get a list of live streams for a given game on youtube

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to fetch data about current live streams for a particular set of games. For example here is a list of live streams for the game "fortnite" https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXzGWycANrrfyBmzX6JMsvQ/live.

Is it possible using youtube's api to fetch the list of live streamers for this game?

Ive tried using the following but items returns an empty array. Where channel_id is `UCXzGWycANrrfyBmzX6JMsvQ`

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```